# Why doesn't overlayroot work properly with a net-booted NFS root on a RPi4?

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, nfs, pxe

**This question has not generated much interest (and no solutions): this may because it is not just a question about Ubuntu and is also not sufficiently documented. I have therefore extensively reformulated it and re-posted it in [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1716358/how-to-netboot-a-raspberry-pi-with-tftp-and-nfs-on-a-synology-nas).**

I can boot 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 from my Synology NAS using network booting and NFS. However, I would like to share the OS on several Pis, so I'm trying to enable an overlay file system which mounts the NFS share read-only. [This](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/) is supposedly not rocket science and it almost works for me. But not quite.

After startup a number of services are not available. `systemctl --failed` shows the following:

```
  UNIT                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                   
● atd.service               loaded failed failed Deferred execution scheduler  
● avahi-daemon.service      loaded failed failed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack       
● systemd-networkd.service  loaded failed failed Network Service               
● systemd-resolved.service  loaded failed failed Network Name Resolution       
● systemd-timesyncd.service loaded failed failed Network Time Synchronization  
● systemd-networkd.socket   loaded failed failed Network Service Netlink Socket

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

6 loaded units listed.
```

I suspect there is a single error in `systemd-networkd.service`, which is having a knock-on effect on the other services.

I have tried starting these services manually, but they all fail, ultimately with the message *operation not supported*. [Internet searches](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22operation+not+supported%22+overlayfs&t=osx&ia=web) reveal other similar cases though without resolution.

I use `overlayroot` and have set `overlayroot="tmpfs:recurse=0"`. The system shows the following for `df -k`:

```
Filesystem                                    1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                             896804        0     896804   0% /dev
tmpfs                                            189252     3024     186228   2% /run
192.168.8.20:/volume3/pxe/nfs/RPi4-Ubuntu/OS 3840789888 15323392 3825347712   1% /media/root-ro
tmpfs-root                                       946248    20972     925276   3% /media/root-rw
overlayroot                                      946248    20972     925276   3% /
tmpfs                                            946248        0     946248   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                              5120        0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                            946248        0     946248   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                                      30057428   156608   28350948   1% /data
tmpfs                                            946248        0     946248   0% /tmp
tmpfs                                            946248        0     946248   0% /var/tmp
tmpfs                                            189248        0     189248   0% /run/user/0
```

so `overlayroot` is doing its stuff.

I have noticed that the NFS root is mounted with version 3 of NFS. I have tried to force the use of version 4, thinking that this might result in a solution, but my Pi and my Synology will only speak NFSv3 to each other during network booting. Adding `vers=4`, `nfsvers=4` or `v4` to `cmdline.txt` only elicits complaints from the Pi about invalid versions or unknown options.

The Pi *can* mount an NFS share with NFSv4 once the machine has started up. However, I suspect that NFSv4 may be a red herring.

Clearly, some parts of the root file system are not accessible. Does anyone know why, please?

Comment: overlayfs seems to work proberly. you better check out why systemd-networkd doesn't work proberly

Comment: The only way I can access anything is as the user root. Other users cannot log in at all. `sudo` doesn't work ('unable to open /etc/sudoers: Operation not supported'). I saw a suggestion that `apparmor` might be getting in the way and disabled it, but that changes nothing. `systemd-networkd` doesn't work because it is run by the user `systemd-network`. If it were a permissions problem I would expect 'permission denied' errors, but I'm getting 'operation not supported'.

Comment: 64 bit and 32 bit Ubuntu both display the same behaviour.

Comment: Check your system log files and check for the runlevel of your "broken" root-only Ubuntu, by using the following commands: `systemctl get-default` and `systemctl list-units --type target --state active`, append output to your original post.

Comment: @paladin I use `overlayroot`: the only config is `overlayroot=“tmpfs:recurse=0”`. The problem occurs straight after booting. Either there is a bug in Ubuntu or I have made a mistake in the TFTP configuration. I assume the latter…

Comment: For your information, an overlay rootfs is not a thing someone does just on the fly. It's a very difficult task which might fail on many different problems. I suggest you do some debugging. If you are lazy, you just might try to use `overlayroot=“tmpfs:recurse=1”` instead and hope for the best. But be warned that this might create other problems.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is relatively simple, though it took a long time to find it.

If you netboot Ubuntu with NFS on an RPi4 the `nfsmount` included with `klibc` (as delivered by Ubuntu) only supports NFS v2 and v3. If you [replace](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/klibc/+bug/1954716/comments/24) that `nfsmount` with one that supports NFSv4 and your root filesystem is successfully mounted by NFSv4, `overlayroot` works as it is supposed to.

Spoiler: it is an upstream (i.e. Debian) [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=409272) that has been around since 2007. Repeat: 2007.

Comment: This discussion and work-around apply only to Ubuntu 20.04. It no longer works in 22.04. I'll start another discussion on that and post a link to it here.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457307/nfsv4-boot-worked-in-20-04-doesnt-in-22-04.

Comment: I'm hitting the same thing, A couple extra data points and questions... When my NFS share is on an Ubuntu machine, overlayroot works just fine. It is only when I put it on a TrueNAS machine that I see these issues. So it seems like just NFSv2/v3 isn't enough to reproduce the problem, but it is definitely a critical part. Any idea why overlayroot may have issues with NFSv2/v3 but not NFSv4?

Answer (score 1):

The root issue appears to be that `overlayfs` behaves incorrectly in certain NFS server configurations. Namely, something goes awry when `overlayfs` is used on top of an NFSv3 export on a server that does not implement [the optional NFSACL protocol extensions for v3](https://lwn.net/Articles/120338/). It looks like this [isn't the only case of `overlayfs` being very brittle with respect to ACLs](https://blog.fai-project.org/posts/overlayfs/). [Apparently there have been (still are?) issues with both v3 and v4 NFS.](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/9/6/378)

I was able to simplify the problem to one not involving boot, but instead just overlayfs and NFS exports. With an NFS export of an Ubuntu image served from an Ubuntu machine (which does implement NFSACLv3) and a directory named `/tmp/overlaygames/` with empty `upper`,`work`, and `overlay` directories within, the following script would run without error:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t nfs -o ro,vers=3 10.99.0.1:/srv/nfs/ubuntu-20.04.3 /media/nfs/
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/media/nfs,upperdir=/tmp/overlaygames/upper,workdir=/tmp/overlaygames/workdir/ overlay /tmp/overlaygames/overlay
ls /tmp/overlaygames/overlay/home
```

Now after running that, run this script to unmount and cleanup:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd /tmp/overlaygames
sudo umount overlay
rm -rf workdir
mkdir workdir
sudo umount /media/nfs
popd
```

Now running the exact same script, but disabling NFSACLv3 client side with the noacl option:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t nfs -o ro,noacl,vers=3 10.99.0.1:/srv/nfs/ubuntu-20.04.3 /media/nfs/
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/media/nfs,upperdir=/tmp/overlaygames/upper,workdir=/tmp/overlaygames/workdir/ overlay /tmp/overlaygames/overlay
ls /tmp/overlaygames/overlay/home
```

will return the familiar

```
ls: cannot open directory '/tmp/overlaygames/overlay/home': Operation not supported
```

Likewise, starting with the first script but putting the NFS export on a FreeNAS/TrueNAS (FreeBSD) machine, will also return `Operation not supported` because FreeBSD does not implement NFSACLv3 (verified by capturing packets).

Interestingly, specifying `vers=2` when working with an NFS share on FreeBSD appears to work just fine. Granted, NFSv2 has some limitations compared to NFSv3.