# NFSv4 boot worked in 20.04, doesn't in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, nfs, initramfs

By dint of a [nasty hack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401854/why-doesnt-overlayroot-work-properly-with-a-net-booted-nfs-root-on-a-rpi4/1423569#1423569) I was able to boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with an NFSv4 root on a Raspberry Pi 4B. When I tried the same with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it failed.

The Raspberry passes kernel parameters to Ubuntu in its `cmdline.txt` file. Mine looks like this:

```
console=serial0,115200
console=tty1
root=/dev/nfs
nfsrootdebug
rootfstype=nfs4
nfsroot=192.168.8.20:/RPi4/Ubuntu/root,vers=4,tcp
rw
ip=dhcp
rootwait
```

(I have replaced space separators with newlines for legibility.)

The string `vers=4` causes an error during parsing of `cmdline.txt` because `klibc-utils` only implements NFSv2 and NFSv3. The nasty hack I referred to above involved replacing the executable `/usr/lib/klibc/bin/nfsmount` with something that didn't check the `vers=` string and proceeded to mount something appropriate using NFSv4.

In 22.04 this no longer works. It appears that 22.04 no longer calls `nfsmount` at all. I deleted `nfsmount` from `libc-utils`completely, did an `update-initramfs -u` and got exactly the same error as with it. So the error I am seeing is not coming from `nfsmount`, whereas in 20.04 it did.

Examination of the source code of `klibc-utils` leads me to believe that the `nfsmount` functionality has been refactored into a file called `.../klibc/usr/kinit/nfsmount/mount.c` which is now (also) called from `/usr/lib/klibc/bin/kinit`.

Could someone confirm this for me? Or anybody with a deeper knowledge of this area of Ubuntu point me in a more productive direction?

The origin of the problem is a [bug in Debian](https://lists.zytor.com/archives/klibc/2007-February/002062.html) that has been known since 2007. I am not an expert in Linux kernels, `initramfs` or the like: in fact I'm only here because I foolishly thought that network booting my Raspberry Pi devices in my home network would be nice and simple, and ended up drilling down. But it would appear that I am going to have to try and fix this ancient bug since no-one else seems to want to.

To help me on my way: could someone point me at how to recompile the `klibc-utils` sources in Ubuntu 22.04?

And any other advice, thoughts and clarifications are always welcome, of course.

Comment: I've just spent an hour chatting with ChatGPT about how to compile `klibc-utils`but neither of us is any the wiser. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a false alarm. I boot the my Pis from my NAS, which stores the RPi Ubuntu partitions in two separate directories (`boot` and `root`), which are later mounted as two separate shares at `/boot/firmware` and `/` respectively.

The `initramfs` phase of the Ubuntu boot occurs from the `initrd.img` file stored in the `boot` directory.

Now, for reasons I do not fully understand, Ubuntu is the proud owner of *two* `initrd.img` files, one in `/boot` and one in `/boot/firmware`. As far as I can tell, they are identical, and they both get updated if you perform `update-initramfs -u`, which you have to do after you have replaced your `nfsmount` image.

I can't run `update-initramfs -u` on the NAS, so I do it on an SD-booted RPi and sync the resultant files back to the NAS. Well, I do *now*. I *was* only sync'ing the `root` share, and each time I rebooted it was with the unchanged `/boot/firmware/initrd.img`, which continued to contain the original NFSv4-unfriendly `nfsmount`.

Sorry.