# RPI3/4 PXE boot ok with ubuntu 20.04 but failed on 22.04 due to missing /lib/systemd in initramfs

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, nfs, pxe

I'm experiencing difficulties with PXE boot on Ubuntu 22.04 and have been trying to resolve this issue for a year.

There are two main problems:

1. The first is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=409272) where NFS version 4 support has been broken since 2007. Further discussion on this issue can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401854/why-doesnt-overlayroot-work-properly-with-a-net-booted-nfs-root-on-a-rpi4), but thankfully, at least version 3 works.
2. The second issue, which I haven't been able to overcome, involves missing folders `/lib/systemd` and `/lib/udev` in initramfs.

I'm unsure where to look to find the reason behind these missing folders and would appreciate any suggestions.

I suspect there's an issue specific to Ubuntu 22.04 since Ubuntu 20.04 works on both RPI3B and RPI4B.

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (initrd.img-5.4.0-1097-raspi):
・✅ SD Card Boot to NFS version 3
・❌ SD Card Boot to NFS version 4
・✅ RPI4B PXE Boot (No SD Card Required)
・✅ RPI3B PXE Boot (SD Card Required for bootcode.bin)

During PXE boot, the Raspberry Pi retrieves the initrd.img from the TFTP server. However, net boot fails because `/lib/systemd` and `/lib/udev` are missing, leading to the absence of eth0. I guarantee that the initramfs is the correct initrd.img, as I have modified `/bin/nfsmount` to support NFS4, addressing the bug(2007) I mentioned. This failure does not occur when booting from an SD Card.

For Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (initrd.img-5.15.0-1044-raspi):
・✅ SD Card Boot to NFS version 3
・✅ SD Card Boot to NFS version 4 (nfsmount replaced with mount.nfs)
・❌ RPI4B PXE Boot (No SD Card Required)
・❌ RPI3B PXE Boot (SD Card Required for bootcode.bin)

The minimal file requirements for SD Card Boot to NFS are:

```
    bootcode.bin
    config.txt
    start.elf
    fixup.dat
    initrd.img
    bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
    overlays/overlay_map.dtb
    overlays/dwc2.dtbo
    cmdline.txt
    vmlinuz
```

cmdline.txt(for better readability though it should be a single line):

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 
console=serial0,115200 
console=tty0 console=tty1 
console=ttyS0,115200 
root=/dev/nfs nfsrootdebug 
nfsroot=192.168.9.10:/rpi3b/,vers=4 
rw ip=dhcp rootwait fixrtc roottimeout=3 
debug break=bottom loglevel=7
```

The `break=bottom` is for debugging and should be removed later.
For rpi4b `nfsroot=192.168.9.10:/srv/nfs/rpi4b8g/,vers=3`

initramfs debug log(`/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: not found` due to entire `/lib/systemd` is missing):

```
(initramfs) cat /run/initramfs/initramfs.debug 
+ unset log_output
+ maybe_break top
+ run_scripts /scripts/init-top
+ initdir=/scripts/init-top
+ '[' '!' -d /scripts/init-top ]
+ shift
+ . /scripts/init-top/ORDER
+ /scripts/init-top/00_mount_efivarfs
+ '[' -e /conf/param.conf ]
+ /scripts/init-top/all_generic_ide
+ '[' -e /conf/param.conf ]
+ /scripts/init-top/blacklist
+ '[' -e /conf/param.conf ]
+ /scripts/init-top/udev
/scripts/init-top/udev: line 24: /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: not found
+ '[' -e /conf/param.conf ]
+ /scripts/init-top/framebuffer
+ '[' -e /conf/param.conf ]
+ /scripts/init-top/console_setup
+ '[' -e /conf/param.conf ]
```

[initrd.img dump vs initramfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUx2a.png)

```
root@iot:/srv/nfs/rpi3b/root/initrd# ls -al lib/
total 132
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 aarch64-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 cryptsetup
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 initramfs-tools
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 91080 Jan 30  2022 klibc-SVGXxscWf9nOevB_HZqdYeSV05I.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    39 Jan  1 01:54 ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -> aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 modprobe.d
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 modules
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jan  1 01:54 udev

(initramfs) ls -al lib/
drwxr-xr-x    3         0 aarch64-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x    2         0 cryptsetup
drwxr-xr-x    6         0 firmware
drwxr-xr-x    3         0 initramfs-tools
-rwxr-xr-x    1     91080 klibc-SVGXxscWf9nOevB_HZqdYeSV05I.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1        39 ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -> aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
drwxr-xr-x    2         0 modprobe.d
drwxr-xr-x    3         0 modules
```

config.txt

```
[all]
kernel=vmlinuz
cmdline=cmdline.txt
initramfs initrd.img followkernel

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2
arm_boost=1

[all]
# Enable the audio output, I2C and SPI interfaces on the GPIO header. As these
# parameters related to the base device-tree they must appear *before* any
# other dtoverlay= specification
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on

# disable rainbow square
#disable_splash=1

# Comment out the following line if the edges of the desktop appear outside
# the edges of your display
disable_overscan=1

# If you have issues with audio, you may try uncommenting the following line
# which forces the HDMI output into HDMI mode instead of DVI (which doesn't
# support audio output)
#hdmi_drive=2

# Enable the serial pins
enable_uart=1

# Autoload overlays for any recognized cameras or displays that are attached
# to the CSI/DSI ports. Please note this is for libcamera support, *not* for
# the legacy camera stack
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1

# Config settings specific to arm64
arm_64bit=1
dtoverlay=dwc2

[pi3]
#device_tree=bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
#dtoverlay=dwc2,pi3-enable-wifi

[cm4]
# Enable the USB2 outputs on the IO board (assuming your CM4 is plugged into
# such a board)
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and it turned out the wrong initrd was being downloaded, so the versions of things in the initrd didn't match the kernel.

Comment: @user10489, thank you for commenting. In case of a mistake, I have specifically replaced `/bin/nfsmount` with a version capable of NFS4, and confirmed that the `initramfs` contains the modified version of `/bin/nfsmount`. Additionally, I copied the same `initrd.img` onto a SD card and attempted to boot from it, which worked well. Even if I had mistakenly copied the wrong version of `initrd.img`, it still doesn't explain the complete absence of `/lib/systemd/`.

Comment: Possibly the initrd is getting corrupted in transfer, probably truncated.  Presuming it is a cpio, check the order the files are in there to confirm where it is getting truncated...

Comment: @user10489 Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed, I need to check whether the file is truncated, as I haven't verified how many bytes were transferred. The kernel logs on both ends also reveal nothing. Probably, using Wireshark for packet capture might provide the necessary information. Also I will try to find what order of '/lib/systemd/` located in `initrd.img`

Comment: Wireshark might help, but it could be truncated in memory after it is transferred, in which case wireshark would be unenlightening.

Comment: @user10489 Do you know how to launch `initrd.img` and `vmlinuz` using `U-Boot`? I'm unsure about which addresses to load them into, as well as where to load the device tree(and what file). I've tried using addresses from the kernel log, but it always results in a panic abort. Having successfully PXE-booted U-Boot and TFTP'd kernels, if I can get the kernel to start from U-Boot, I might be able to circumvent the truncation issue.

Comment: I've not used U-boot, but I suspect there isn't a "correct" specific address.  Probably have to do some math to calculate correct addresses.

Comment: @user10489 I have successfully netbooted to U-Boot and then tftp kernel then started kernel from u-boot using command `setenv bootargs "earlyprintk console=ttyAMA0 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs nfsrootdebug nfsroot=192.168.9.10:/rpi3b/,vers=4 rw ip=dhcp rootwait fixrtc roottimeout=3 debug loglevel=7"` followed by `booti ${kernel_addr_r} ${ramdisk_addr_r}:${filesize} ${fdt_addr}` with `vmlinuz`, `bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb` and `initrd.img` everything works as it should. However, when I try direct boot from kernel without U-Boot, I encounter the same '/lib/systemd' missing issue. So many pits to fill!